# Why does my page need to have a label for .hide()?

Tags: jquery, label

Why does my page need to have a `<label id="error"></label>` to run `.hide()`?

Once this label is removed, my `.hide()` method won't work at all.

I have a table call `aTable` and I want to hide it after form processing.

```
$("#aTable").hide( "blind", 1000 );
```

This code can only be run if I have the label with `id="error"`. Once I remove this label, the method won't work anymore?

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please post your complete code. And `.hide()` doesn't need a label to work.

Comment: you have made absolutely no connection in your code between a label and a table. Question makes no sense without making this connection. Are you using jQueryUI in page in order to use `blind` effect?

Comment: Can I ask that you [show us what you're doing](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Because there's no reason that a `label` element is, in any way, required for the `hide()` method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your browser's debugging tools to set a breakpoint at the line that calls `.hide(...)`.  I'm about 80% certain it will never even be hit once you remove the label.

I'm thinking some code before the `.hide` expects to alter the contents of your label.  With the label gone, something like `document.getElementById('error')` would return null, and any attempt to treat that null value as an element would throw an error, killing the script before `hide` is called.

Without my having seen the code, though, this is just a rather-educated guess.  :)